# Transit visa for connecting flights

Tags: airports, dubai

I will have a connecting flight in Dubai going to UK and vice versa when coming back here in the Philippines. I am wondering if I still need to get a visa when I am only staying in the airport to wait for my next plane for about 4-5 hours only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single itenary and bags are checked through, then you don't need a transit visa. This is applicable for all countries and citizens.